# Error: Cannot find module 'cors'

Tags: node.js, json, heroku, cors, tilda

Не могу поставить cors модуль на node js express. на  тильде имеется блок кода.

```
<script>
//  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
//      let form = document.querySelector("#form309365517");
//      form.addEventListener("click", sendPost());
//      });
     
//     function sendPost() {

        console.log("click");
        let httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
        // httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        let url = "https:automatic-contracts-edukoht.herokuapp.com/api/generate-pdf";
        httpRequest.open('POST', url)
        httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'https://automatic-contracts-edukoht.herokuapp.com/api/generate-pdf');
        httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

        httpRequest.send(JSON.stringify(
            { 
                
                "userType": "client",
                "country": "EST",
                "language": "RU",
            
                "parentName": "TOOMAS",
                "parentSurname": "Mihhailova",
                "parentEmail": "parentTest@gmail.com",       
                "parentPhoneNumber": "1111111", 
            
                "childName": "Viktor",
                "childSurname": "Mihhailovski",   
                "childEmail": "test@mail.ru",      
                "childPhoneNumber": "1234114",
            
                "childIDcode": "3786481243",       
                "childSchool": "Test school", 
            
                "adress": "Tallllllll 48-15",
                "town": "Test",
                "postIndex": "11111"

                
            }
            ));
        
        // }

    // }
    

</script>
```

и мне надо отправить json post запросом на приложения на heroku. Но столкнулся с такой штукой как cors... На сервере же я прописал:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://automatic-contracts-edukoht.herokuapp.com');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});
```

так же пытался прописать `npm install cors` . И `npm link cors` и `npm install`, в консоли на heroku. устанавливалось но по-прежнему,  я не могу отправить запрос, в консоли выдает `Error: Cannot find module 'cors'`
. подскажет кто в чем дело или что я делаю не так?

консоль хрома:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
консоль приложухи:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что содержит package.json:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что в package-lock.json:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `let url = "https:automatic-contracts-edukoht.herokuapp.com` <- **https://**

Comment: @nörbörnën не сработало

Comment: npm install cors --save

Comment: @nörbörnën неа, всеравно что то не так.

Comment: @nörbörnën мб надо с зависимостями поработать?

Comment: может. на основании информации, которую вы написали в вопросе, можно сколько угодно гадать на кофейной гуще

Comment: @nörbörnën, так скажите чего конкретно не хватает, я добавлю и правлю, ибо я в node js совсем зеленый.

Comment: В Access-Control-Allow-Origin должен быть домен сайта который хочет получить доступ (`edukoht.tilda.ws` видимо)

Comment: @AlexeyTen неа, не сработало... По-прежнему выкидывает ошибку cors

Comment: посмотрите на ваш запрос со стороны: у вас есть приложение на nodejs, которое не запускается на специфическом хостинге; что ru.so знает об этом приложении - код одной мидлвари. ну ок

Comment: хотите продолжать викторину? может быть в package.json пакет cors прописан в devDependencies

Comment: @nörbörnën что в package.json закинул в вопрос как правку.

Comment: пропишите в dependencies `"cors": "^2.8.5"`

Comment: @nörbörnën npm ERR! cipm can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.

Comment: @nörbörnën что в package-lock.json тоже кинул в правки в вопрос.

Comment: npm install запустить

Comment: @nörbörnën неа, не хочет стартовать.  npm ERR! Missing: cors@^2.8.5 так и висит.